# (Direct) AWS Lambda invocation response status code is 200 despite unhandled function error

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda which is designed for direct invocation from multiple applications within my team's service landscape. I'm writing a wrapper class which will perform this invocation, and associated validation and error detection / handling in the Lambda's response.

By design, the Lambda terminates with an unhandled exception if runtime validation of the invocation parameters fails. But I didn't expect to find that **in spite of an unhandled function error, the `status_code` of the invocation response is 200:**

```ruby
[1] pry(main)> lambda_client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
=> #<Aws::Lambda::Client>
[2] pry(main)> invocation_response = lambda_client.invoke(function_name: 'jwt-tokens-dev-AccessTokenCreator') 
=> #<struct Aws::Lambda::Types::InvocationResponse
 status_code=200,
 function_error="Unhandled",
 log_result=nil,
 payload=#<StringIO:0x007f91c1749028>,
 executed_version="$LATEST">
[3] pry(main)> invocation_response.payload.string
=> "{\"errorMessage\": \"Required parameters are missing: role, sub, sub_type\", \"errorType\": \"ParamMissingError\", \"stackTrace\": [[\"/var/task/handler.py\", 15, \"access_token_creator\", \"return access_token_creator_handler(event, context)\"], [\"/var/task/access_token_creator.py\", 32, \"handler\", \"params = _validate_event_params(event)\"], [\"/var/task/access_token_creator.py\", 97, \"_validate_event_params\", \"raise ParamMissingError('Required parameters are missing: %s' % ', '.join(missing_params))\"]]}"
[4] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(invocation_response.payload.string)
=> {"errorMessage"=>"Required parameters are missing: role, sub, sub_type",
 "errorType"=>"ParamMissingError",
 "stackTrace"=>
  [["/var/task/handler.py", 15, "access_token_creator", "return access_token_creator_handler(event, context)"],
   ["/var/task/access_token_creator.py", 32, "handler", "params = _validate_event_params(event)"],
   ["/var/task/access_token_creator.py",
    97,
    "_validate_event_params",
    "raise ParamMissingError('Required parameters are missing: %s' % ', '.join(missing_params))"]]}
```

Is it expected that the status code of the response of a direct Lambda invocation would be 200, despite an unhandled function error? I want to implement proper error response detection in my wrapper class, and **searching for the key "errorType" in the top-level of the JSON response doesn't really seem so robust.**

Comment: There is already some discussion of Lambda errors and status codes, in the context of API Gateway Lambda integrations, in the documentation, on StackOverflow, and elsewhere --- but my use case is a _direct Lambda invocation from application code._

Comment: Confirmation that the 200 is expected, here:   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html ...4xx and 5xx are only used for request-related issues and service-related failures.  If the function starts and finishes (for request/response, regardless of any reported error), that's a 200, presumably designed that way because your *request to invoke* was processed successfully.  The fact that an error occurred does not mean the service itself failed or that the request was otherwise rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution -- too obvious, but not enough to distract from the "200" `status_code` -- is to check if `function_error` is `nil`.

The value is `nil` in the event of successful invocation:

```
[8] pry(main)> invocation_response = lambda_client.invoke(function_name: 'jwt-tokens-dev-AccessTokenCreator', payload: ActiveSupport::JSON::encode(sub:3285397, sub_type:'user', role:'admin'))
=> #<struct Aws::Lambda::Types::InvocationResponse
 status_code=200,
 function_error=nil,
 log_result=nil,
 payload=#<StringIO:0x007f91c2a2eeb8>,
 executed_version="$LATEST">
```

Otherwise it has the value `'Unhandled'` or `'Handled'`:

> #### function_error ⇒ String
>
> Indicates whether an error occurred while executing the Lambda function. If an error occurred this field will
>   have one of two values; Handled or Unhandled. Handled errors are
>   errors that are reported by the function while the Unhandled errors
>   are those detected and reported by AWS Lambda. Unhandled errors
>   include out of memory errors and function timeouts. For information
>   about how to report an Handled error, see Programming Model.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Types/InvocationResponse.html#function_error-instance_method